# Map through JSON object in DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, json, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have stored my column as a JSON object in my DynamoDB table.

```
receiver:[{id: 'r1', name: 'a'},{id: 'r2', name: 'b'},{id: 'r3', name: 'c'},]
```

I want to get the item if r1 is a receiver.

I tried using the FilterExpression receiver[0].id = 'r1' and it did return the item. However, what if the index of r1 was not at 0? How would i be able to map through the object?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB is not great for search, especially within complex attribute types like lists or maps.  While useful, these complex attribute types are *not* well suited for search.

One place where they can be useful is if you have known keys.  For example, imaging an attribute named `phone_numbers` that stores home, work and cell phone numbers:

```
phone_numbers:{
  home: "(555) 123-4567"},
  work: "(555) 246-8910"},
  cell: "(123) 345-1231"}
}
```

Storing your data in this way allows you to fetch a users home/work/cell phone number.  However, it does *not* support searching for phone numbers by area code.

If you need to search the data stored in your complex attribute, you'll need to get the data in a more useful format (e.g. in it's own attribute).  Better yet, incorporate it into your primary key!